# CSS Dropdown Nav, Show on Click instead of Hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation

https://jsfiddle.net/ax92n1hq/3/

This navigation works exactly how I want it to on the normal size screen.  However, inside...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
    ....
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the dropdown to show on-click instead of on-hover.  I am 99% sure this is possible in CSS.  I saw someone ask this before, and got an answer.  But now that I need to implement, it, I can't find that post again.

Comment: You may want to try the [:active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aactive) pseudo-class which works on links. I know you are working over the `ul` and `li` elements, but for the rule you specified you may want to work with the links instead.

Comment: One of the first things I tried was changing .nav ul li:hover > ul to .nav ul li:active> ul and .nav ul li:focus> ul.  All of them still show the dropdown on hover :-(

Comment: Google "checkbox hack"

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with pure CSS as far as I know. If you really can't use JS you may try to use some hidden checkboxes and put the toogle button as a label. Then style your menu depending on the state of the checkbox.

Comment: It IS possible with pure CSS.  See this example.  http://koen.kivits.com/articles/pure-css-menu/  I'm just having trouble getting it to work for me!

Comment: Have you tried opening the jsfiddle on mobile? It works for me as is.

Comment: @Grekomp That may be true, but `:hover` can cause some unexpected behaviour on touch devices.

Comment: The method suggested by OP doesn't work on ios at all so that is a bigger problem

Answer (score 0):

First: Please post your code here, so we don't all have to go to JSFiddle just to see it.

Your proposed solution uses the pseudo-class `:focus` on the parent `<li>` of the `<ul>` you want to show. This `:focus` is achieved by clicking it. However, the `<a>` is "on top" of the `<li>` and "on top" of the `<a>` is a `<span>` which is getting `:focus`. Unfortunately there is no parent selector is CSS (yet). So in this way you won't get around with just CSS, but need some JS, change your HTML or use the hidden checkbox trick.

You can easily see what's going on in the inspector of your browser.

Comment: Ok thanks. Good advice. About JSFiddle.... On other questions I've posted large amounts of code, and people have said, "Don't do that!  Just use JSFIddle!"  Seems you can't always please everyone.